# importing pow function from __future__ in python

Tags: python-3.x

does importing with `__future__` in python not allow us to use all the functions, like I want to use `pow` introduced in 3.8 which is a bit modified to get inverse like computing an inverse for 38 modulo 97 ?

Also, using `__future__` import i.e. import **future**, makes us use which python version, a recent one in development or any other?

docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#pow : see for pow in version 3.8

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The `pow` function has been around since forever.

Comment: I know but the it's improved in 3.8 compared to 3.7. see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#pow

Comment: Ah, got it now. No, you can only import those listed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/__future__.html).